# Module build failed (from ./node_modules/ts-loader/index.js): Error: TypeScript emitted no output for

Tags: reactjs, typescript, webpack, ts-loader, single-spa

```
**Error**
**ERROR in ./src/app-chat.tsx
Module build failed (from ./node_modules/ts-loader/index.js):
Error: TypeScript emitted no output for D:\React\kasper\new-kasper\kasper-ui-chat\chat\src\app-chat.tsx.
    at makeSourceMapAndFinish (D:\React\kasper\new-kasper\kasper-ui-chat\chat\node_modules\ts-loader\dist\index.js:52:18)
    at successLoader (D:\React\kasper\new-kasper\kasper-ui-chat\chat\node_modules\ts-loader\dist\index.js:39:5)
    at Object.loader (D:\React\kasper\new-kasper\kasper-ui-chat\chat\node_modules\ts-loader\dist\index.js:22:5)
```

webpack 5.74.0 compiled with 1 error in 7299 ms**

**Webpack**

```
const { merge } = require('webpack-merge');
const Dotenv = require('dotenv-webpack');
const TsconfigPathsPlugin = require('tsconfig-paths-webpack-plugin');
const FilterWarningsPlugin = require('webpack-filter-warnings-plugin');
const path = require('path');
const singleSpaDefaults = require('webpack-config-single-spa-react');
const override = require('./config-overrides.js');

module.exports = (webpackConfigEnv, argv) => {
  const defaultConfig = singleSpaDefaults({
    orgName: 'app',
    projectName: 'chat',
    webpackConfigEnv,
    argv,
    override,
  });

  return merge(defaultConfig, {
    resolve: {
      extensions: ['.ts', '.tsx', '.js'],
      preferRelative: true,
      alias: {
        containers: path.resolve(__dirname, 'src/containers'),
        components: path.resolve(__dirname, 'src/components'),
        layouts: path.resolve(__dirname, 'src/layouts'),
        stores: path.resolve(__dirname, 'src/stores'),
        hooks: path.join(__dirname, 'src/hooks'),
        context: path.join(__dirname, 'src/context'),
        assets: path.join(__dirname, 'src/assets'),
        helpers: path.join(__dirname, 'src/helpers'),
      },
      // plugins: [new TsconfigPathsPlugin()],
    },
    devServer: {
      port: 8500,
    },
    plugins: [
      new Dotenv({
        path: './.env.development',
      }),
      new FilterWarningsPlugin({
        exclude:
          /There are multiple modules with names that only differ in casing/,
      }),
    ],
    output: {
      path: path.resolve(__dirname, 'build'),
      assetModuleFilename: 'assets/[name][ext]',
    },
    module: {
      rules: [
        {
          test: /\.json$/,
          use: 'json-loader',
        },
        {
          test: /\.(js)x?$/,
          exclude: /node_modules/,
          use: 'babel-loader',
        },
        {
          test: /\.(ts)x?$/,
          exclude: /node_modules/,
          use: 'ts-loader',
        },
      ],
    },
  });
};
```

---

**tsconfig.json**

```
{
  "extends": "ts-config-single-spa",
  "compilerOptions": {
    "jsx": "react-jsx",
    "declarationDir": "build",
    "baseUrl": "./src",
  },
  "files": ["src/app-chat.tsx"],
  "include": ["src/**/*"],
  "exclude": ["src/**/*.test*"],
}
```

**.babel**

```
{
  "presets": [
    "@babel/preset-env",
    "@babel/preset-react"
  ],
  "plugins": [["@babel/plugin-proposal-decorators", { "legacy": true }], "inline-react-svg" ]
}
```

**package.json**

```
{
  "name": "@app/login",
  "scripts": {
    "start": "webpack serve",
    "start:standalone": "webpack serve --env standalone",
    "build": "concurrently yarn:build:*",
    "build:webpack": "webpack --mode=production",
    "analyze": "webpack --mode=production --env analyze",
    "lint": "eslint src --ext js,ts,tsx",
    "lint:fix": "eslint src --ext js,ts,tsx --fix",
    "format": "prettier --write .",
    "check-format": "prettier --check .",
    "test": "cross-env BABEL_ENV=test jest",
    "watch-tests": "cross-env BABEL_ENV=test jest --watch",
    "prepare": "cd .. && husky install",
    "coverage": "cross-env BABEL_ENV=test jest --coverage",
    "build:types": "tsc"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@babel/core": "^7.15.0",
    "@babel/eslint-parser": "^7.15.0",
    "@babel/plugin-transform-runtime": "^7.15.0",
    "@babel/preset-env": "^7.15.0",
    "@babel/preset-react": "^7.14.5",
    "@babel/preset-typescript": "^7.15.0",
    "@babel/runtime": "^7.15.3",
    "@testing-library/jest-dom": "^5.14.1",
    "@testing-library/react": "^12.0.0",
    "@types/js-cookie": "^3.0.2",
    "@types/testing-library__jest-dom": "^5.14.1",
    "babel-jest": "^27.0.6",
    "babel-loader": "^8.2.5",
    "concurrently": "^6.2.1",
    "cross-env": "^7.0.3",
    "eslint": "^7.32.0",
    "eslint-config-prettier": "^8.3.0",
    "eslint-config-ts-react-important-stuff": "^3.0.0",
    "eslint-plugin-prettier": "^3.4.1",
    "husky": "^7.0.2",
    "identity-obj-proxy": "^3.0.0",
    "jest": "^27.0.6",
    "jest-cli": "^27.0.6",
    "json-loader": "^0.5.7",
    "prettier": "^2.3.2",
    "pretty-quick": "^3.1.1",
    "ts-config-single-spa": "^3.0.0",
    "ts-loader": "^9.4.1",
    "tsconfig-paths-webpack-plugin": "^4.0.0",
    "typescript": "^4.3.5",
    "webpack": "^5.51.1",
    "webpack-cli": "^4.8.0",
    "webpack-config-single-spa-react": "^4.0.0",
    "webpack-config-single-spa-react-ts": "^4.0.0",
    "webpack-config-single-spa-ts": "^4.0.0",
    "webpack-dev-server": "^4.0.0",
    "webpack-merge": "^5.8.0"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "@date-io/moment": "^2.13.1",
    "@emotion/react": "^11.10.4",
    "@emotion/styled": "^11.10.4",
    "@material-ui/core": "^4.12.4",
    "@material-ui/icons": "^4.11.3",
    "@material-ui/pickers": "^3.3.10",
    "@mui/material": "^5.10.8",
    "@sentry/react": "^6.19.7",
    "@sentry/tracing": "^6.19.7",
    "@types/jest": "^27.0.1",
    "@types/react": "^17.0.19",
    "@types/react-dom": "^17.0.9",
    "@types/systemjs": "^6.1.1",
    "@types/webpack-env": "^1.16.2",
    "awesome-phonenumber": "^2.72.0",
    "aws-amplify": "^3.3.2",
    "aws-amplify-react": "^5.1.9",
    "bootstrap": "^5.1.3",
    "dotenv-webpack": "^8.0.1",
    "eslint-plugin-jest": "^27.1.0",
    "eslint-plugin-jest-dom": "^4.0.2",
    "eslint-plugin-react": "^7.31.8",
    "eslint-plugin-storybook": "^0.6.4",
    "eslint-plugin-testing-library": "^5.7.2",
    "firebase": "^8.2.2",
    "formik": "^2.2.9",
    "formik-material-ui": "^3.0.1",
    "formik-material-ui-lab": "0.0.8",
    "formik-material-ui-pickers": "0.0.12",
    "js-cookie": "^3.0.1",
    "logrocket": "^3.0.0",
    "logrocket-react": "^5.0.1",
    "mobx": "^5.15.6",
    "mobx-devtools-mst": "^0.9.22",
    "mobx-react": "^6.3.1",
    "mobx-react-devtools": "^6.1.1",
    "mobx-react-router": "^4.1.0",
    "mobx-state-tree": "^3.17.2",
    "mobx-utils": "^5.6.1",
    "react": "^17.0.2",
    "react-dom": "^17.0.2",
    "react-helmet": "^6.1.0",
    "react-password-strength-bar": "^0.4.0",
    "react-query": "^3.34.16",
    "react-router-dom": "^5.2.0",
    "single-spa": "^5.9.3",
    "single-spa-react": "^4.3.1",
    "yup": "^0.32.11",
    "yup-phone": "1.3.1"
  },
  "types": "dist/app-login.d.ts",
  "resolutions": {
    "@types/react": "^17.0.2"
  }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

In webpack add :

```
module: {
      rules: [
        {
          test: /\.json$/,
          use: 'json-loader',
        },
        {
          test: /\.(js)x?$/,
          exclude: /node_modules/,
          use: 'babel-loader',
        },
        {
          test: /\.(ts)x?$/,
          exclude: /node_modules|\.d\.ts$/, // this line as well
          use: {
            loader: 'ts-loader',
            options: {
            compilerOptions: {
            noEmit: false, // this option will solve the issue
           },
          },
         },
        },
      ],
    },
```

Usually webpack hangs when declaration is true without creating d.ts files and that causes errors. By default is true so all you need it to set it to false.

Comment: I just tried it and still got the same error

Comment: there are other options

Comment: I have updated the code, try now

Comment: That didn't help, either.